# next themes - Hydration Issue on first mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using the next themes package for dark mode and light mode. I thought I did the installation correctly by checking the repo, but I'm seeing the following issue.

Here is the behavior I expect in my project;

The theme of the web page should be loaded according to the user's system settings on the first load. Then the user can switch between themes with the toggle button.

What happens in my project:

The website is loaded according to the system settings on the first load, but. The toggle button and the image element in the navigation bar do not follow this preference. So for example, if the user's system setting is dark mode on the first page load, the website is loaded in dark mode, but the navbar image element and the toggle button icon are loaded for light mode without following this setting.

How can I fix this problem?

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AiOutlineClose, AiOutlineMail, AiOutlineMenu } from "react-icons/ai";
import { FaGithub, FaLinkedinIn } from "react-icons/fa";
import { BsFillPersonLinesFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import NavLogo from "../public/assets/navLogo.svg";
import DarkNavLogo from "../public/assets/darkNavLogo.svg";
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import ToggleButton from "./ToggleButton";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [nav, setNav] = useState(false);
  const [shadow, setShadow] = useState(false);
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  const handleNav = () => {
    setNav(!nav);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleShadow = () => {
      if (window.scrollY >= 90) {
        setShadow(true);
      } else {
        setShadow(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleShadow);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className={
        shadow
          ? "fixed w-full h-20 shadow-xl z-[100] ease-in-out duration-300 px-4 md:px-8 lg:px-16 bg-jelly-bean-50 dark:bg-jelly-bean-950"
          : "fixed w-full h-20 z-[100] px-4 md:px-8 lg:px-16 bg-jelly-bean-50 dark:bg-jelly-bean-950"
      }
    >
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center w-full h-full px-2 2xl:px-16 ">
        <Link href="/">
          {mounted && (
            <Image
              src={theme === "dark" ? DarkNavLogo : NavLogo}
              alt="Emre Turan - Developer Logo"
              width={125}
              height={125}
              className="cursor-pointer"
            />
          )}
        </Link>

        <div>
          <ul className="hidden md:flex ">
            <li className="ml-10 text-m border-b border-transparent hover:border-current">
              <Link href="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="ml-10 text-m border-b border-transparent hover:border-current">
              <Link href="/#about" scroll={false}>
                About
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="ml-10 text-m border-b border-transparent hover:border-current">
              <Link href="/#skills" scroll={false}>
                {" "}
                Skills
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="ml-10 text-m border-b border-transparent hover:border-current">
              <Link href="/#projects" scroll={false}>
                Projects
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="ml-10 text-m border-b border-transparent hover:border-current">
              <Link href="/resume">Resume</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="ml-10 text-m border-b border-transparent hover:border-current">
              <Link href="/#contact" scroll={false}>
                Contact
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="ml-10">
              <ToggleButton />
            </li>
          </ul>
          {/* Hamburger Icon */}
          <div className="md:hidden flex">
            <ToggleButton size={25} />
            <div onClick={handleNav}>
              <AiOutlineMenu size={25} className="ml-2" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Mobile Menu */}
      {/* Overlay */}
      <div
        className={
          nav ? "md:hidden fixed left-0 top-0 w-full h-screen bg-black/70" : ""
        }
      >
        {/* Side Drawer Menu */}
        <div
          className={
            nav
              ? "fixed left-0 top-0 w-[75%] sm:w-[60%] md:w-[45%] h-screen bg-jelly-bean-50 p-10 ease-in duration-500 dark:bg-jelly-bean-950"
              : "fixed left-[-100%] top-0 p-10 ease-in duration-500"
          }
        >
          <div>
            <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-between">
              <Link href="/">
                {mounted && (
                  <Image
                    src={theme === "dark" ? DarkNavLogo : NavLogo}
                    alt="Emre Turan - Developer Logo"
                    width={100}
                    height={125}
                    className="cursor-pointer"
                  />
                )}
              </Link>

              <div
                onClick={handleNav}
                className="rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-gray-400 p-3 cursor-pointer dark:shadow-jelly-bean-900 dark:bg-jelly-bean-50 dark:text-jelly-bean-900"
              >
                <AiOutlineClose />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="border-b border-gray-300 my-4">
              <p className="w-[85%] md:w-[90%] py-4">
                Let&apos;s build something together
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="py-4 flex flex-col">
            <ul className="uppercase">
              <Link href="/">
                <li onClick={() => setNav(false)} className="py-4 text-sm">
                  Home
                </li>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/#about">
                <li onClick={() => setNav(false)} className="py-4 text-sm">
                  About
                </li>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/#skills">
                <li onClick={() => setNav(false)} className="py-4 text-sm">
                  Skills
                </li>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/#projects">
                <li onClick={() => setNav(false)} className="py-4 text-sm">
                  Projects
                </li>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/resume">
                <li onClick={() => setNav(false)} className="py-4 text-sm">
                  Resume
                </li>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/#contact">
                <li onClick={() => setNav(false)} className="py-4 text-sm">
                  Contact
                </li>
              </Link>
            </ul>
            <div className="pt-40">
              <p className="uppercase tracking-widest text-jelly-bean-600 dark:text-jelly-bean-200">
                Let&#39;s Connect
              </p>
              <div className="flex items-center justify-between my-4 w-full sm:w-[80%]">
                <a
                  href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/emre-turan/"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer"
                >
                  <div className="rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-gray-400 p-3 cursor-pointer hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-300">
                    <FaLinkedinIn />
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a
                  href="https://github.com/etdesign"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer"
                >
                  <div className="rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-gray-400 p-3 cursor-pointer hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-300">
                    <FaGithub />
                  </div>
                </a>
                <Link href="/#contact">
                  <div
                    onClick={() => setNav(!nav)}
                    className="rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-gray-400 p-3 cursor-pointer hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-300"
                  >
                    <AiOutlineMail />
                  </div>
                </Link>
                <Link href="/resume">
                  <div
                    onClick={() => setNav(!nav)}
                    className="rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-gray-400 p-3 cursor-pointer hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-300"
                  >
                    <BsFillPersonLinesFill />
                  </div>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import DarkModeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DarkMode";
import LightModeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LightMode";

const ToggleButton = () => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();

  useEffect(() => setMounted(true), []);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark")}
      className="transition-all duration-100"
    >
      {mounted && (theme === "dark" ? <LightModeIcon /> : <DarkModeIcon />)}
    </button>
  );
};

export default ToggleButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are ways to fix this using cookies to inform the server side about the theme changing... But the syntax of this escapes me.